# Excel File Broken when syncing with rsync

Tags: microsoft-excel, backup, rsync, wsl2

I want to backup files with rsync.

I have noticed that Excel files are copied the first time, but after editing the file, the file is broken in the backup folder.

It does not matter if you run rsync locally or with SSH.

How to reproduce:

1. Create a folder c:\rsync-source
2. Create within this folder a new excel file
3. Open Ubuntu WSL
4. Run  `rsync --delete --delete-excluded --partial --inplace --progress --checksum --append -avre ssh /mnt/c/rsync-source /mnt/c/rsync-target`
5. Open the destination Excel file -> **It opens**
6. Do some significant changes within the source Excel file (The checksum seems to be the same sometimes when only small changes are done)
7. Run rsync command again
8. Open Excel file in destination again -> **"We found a problem with some content filename.xlsx. Do you want us to try and recover as much as we can?"**

The restoring process works on simple Excel sheets but in my real world excel file it can not be restored.

So the issue is not Excel I guess. The issue seems to be with rsync copy command.

OS: WSL Ubuntu on Windows 10

Excel: 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are over-complicating the command line. Try this instead:

```
rsync --delete --progress -av /mnt/c/rsync-source /mnt/c/rsync-target
```

Notes

- Using `--partial` can leave an incomplete destination file. Over a network this can be an advantage if you re-run the `rsync` command and let it complete the copy, but for transfers between a local source and a local destination all that happens is that the incomplete destination file is deleted and the full copy retried.
- Using `--checksum` is unnecessary unless your files are updated without the modification time being correspondingly updated.
- There's no need to give a network transfer command (`-e ssh`) when you're copying locally, as it's ignored for such copies.
- The recursion flag (`-r`) is implied when you use archive mode (`-a`).
- Consider carefully whether you really do want `--delete-excluded`. In almost all cases this is a dangerous and inappropriate flag to include and it's better just to use `--delete`.
- Although you don't use it in your question, the `--inplace` flag is also largely irrelevant for local-to-local copies. It's most appropriately used when there is a very large file being transferred across a network and there is insufficient space on the destination to retain a copy of an original file while building its replacement. This flag trades space for efficiency.

Comment: Thanks for your correction. Generally, I simplified my question because in real life I am using a network connection to transfer the data.

Comment: @basti500 that makes `rsync` work completely differently. Please never simplify `rsync` issues like that

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by `--inplace` and `--partial`. This seems to break the excel file.

As I also want to transfer parts of big files I will add  --partial-dir=.rsync-partial.

So the full working command is then like that:

```
rsync --delete --delete-excluded --partial-dir=.rsync-partial --progress --checksum -avre ssh /mnt/c/rsync-source /mnt/c/rsync-targe``
```